# I can't make any edits in my etc folder

Tags: permissions, etc

Every time I try to edit a file in `/etc` I get "access denied".

I tried using different text editors and nautilus and I couldn't save or change any files there.

I don't understand. Am I not supposed to have this access?

What do I do now?

Comment: ONLY edit files in `/etc`if you know what you are doing. Files are quite sensitive in there.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have root privilege.

Try:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/file.txt
```

Comment: i made myself root, and do i have to install gedit

Comment: i dd and it is workin

Comment: "i made myself root" - So you are doing all your work as a user with root privileges? That's a really bad idea, you should `su root` if you need root access.

Answer (score 0):

You can have root access with the command

```
gksu nautilus
```

This gives you a GUI access of the files in root.But be careful with what you change in there.

Comment: gksu provided me with a warning that.. `(gksu:4370): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display`

Comment: You are probably running this command as root, and root probably doesn't have an active desktop session.